# How to wrap only content fields that use RTE in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

I would like to wrap all fields (or only bodytext) that use RTE in backend, any ideas how I could achieve this via TypoScript? I've tried:

```
tt_content.text.default {
 20 = TEXT
 20.field = bodytext
 20.wrap = <div class="rte">|</div>
}
```

But no luck.

Comment: You could analyze TCA definition to define, which fields has RTE transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a user function. Because whether the RTE is used or not is not know in frontend rendering. Or you need to do this for all fields directly instead for default.

Answer (score 0):

Following script will help you to wrap RTE

```
tt_content.text.20.wrap = <div class="wrapRTE">|</div>
```

For more information you may visit https://jainishsenjaliya.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/how-to-wrap-the-content-in-rte-typo3/